# Wordpress is asking for FTP, is it some package missing?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, amazon-ec2, lamp

I install a LAMP/Wordpress on Amazon EC2. The blog works fine. However on downloading themes, it asks me for FTP credentials. I try to chmod some folders but it didn't work.

I used to have a shared hosting for Wordpress and it never asked for FTP. So I think maybe there is some packages missing? So far I have installed:

apache2 php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin

I really don't want to install FTP server unless I have to.

Comment: Who are the owners and what are the rights on the folders? Where is it located? /var/www?

Comment: Just FYI - I know you have your own server/hosting on EC2 but I'm throwing this out there anyway:  Wordpress.com does not allow FTP access.  I think only WordPress.org allows it.  See Wordpress's official document on FTP access... http://en.support.wordpress.com/ftp-access/

Comment: As another FYI - why did this get voted down?

Comment: hi ben, I believe you are right. the only way is to chmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems EC2 is not good with FTP

I changed the owner of the Wordpress folder t